# Error: Invalid value for region: project: required field is not set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

On **GCP**, I'm trying to create **a Cloud Run service** and **a Serverless Network Endpoint Group** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-813137"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "hello-world"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/myproject-813137/hello-world:latest"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}

resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "cloudrun_neg" {
  provider              = google-beta
  name                  = "neg"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = "asia-northeast1"
  cloud_run {
    service = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error: Invalid value for region: project: required field is not set

Are there any mistakes in my **Terraform** code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **"provider = google-beta"** from **"google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group"**:

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "cloudrun_neg" {
  # provider              = google-beta // Here to remove
  name                  = "neg"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = "asia-northeast1"
  cloud_run {
    service = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  }
}
```

Even though you have already defined **provider "google"** below, you redefined **"provider = google-beta"** in **"google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group"**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-813137"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}
```

That's why you got this error:

> Error: Invalid value for region: project: required field is not set